# Recursion and non recursion that count number in singly linked list

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Could you please check if these algorithms are currect, if there is mistake, currect me please! Thanks

A non-recursive algorithm:

```
Int i =0; 

If(singly.hasNext())
{
     i++;
}
else
{
    Return i;
}
```

A recursive algorithm:

```
Algorithm count(n): 

if(n=null) 
{
     return 0;
} 
else
{ 
   return 1+count(n.getNext());
}
```

Comment: In recursive algorithm the function count should be int, rest looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first algorithm look bad to me.

You are not itering throught the list. This should be better :

```
while(singly.hasNext())
{
     singly.next();
     i++;
}
return i;
```

It will iterate the list until there is no more element, adding +1 each time. when there are no more elements, it goes out of the while and return i;